# Cannot import Plugins to stm32cubeide (Eclipse IDE)

Tags: eclipse, plugins, ide, stm32cubeide

I'm trying to import the plugin [Columns for eclipse](https://sourceforge.net/projects/columns4eclipse/) to the stm32cubeide.
I tried severals ways, without luck.

First I tried the official way per Help > Install new software.
The wizards shows the following error: "Could not find jar"

After some google research I tried to paste the .jar and its extracted content to a new created folder **stm32cubeide_home/dropins**. This does not work either.

My last idea about this problem was to insert the extracted .jar direct to **stm32cubeide_home/plugins** but again no luck.

Is there a way to import Eclipse plugins, which are not in the official marketplace, into stm32cubeide?

The plugin works fine Eclipse IDE for C/C++ V4.16.

Comment: Does _File > Import...: Install > From Existing Installation_ using your Eclipse IDE for C/C++ 2020-06 (4.16) installation work?

Comment: No. The same error message like in eclipse appears (Could not find .jar)
The import is succesfull by droping the file in the **dropins'** folder.